# MDB is inserting duplicate records

Tags: java, oracle, queue, ejb-3.0, jboss5.x

I am using JBOSS 5.1.2 MDB to consume entity messages placed on a queue. The message producer can produce multiple messages for the same entity. These message entities are defined by their entity number. (msg_entity_no) I must insert a record into an existing entity table only if the the entity does not exist else I must update the existing record.
The existing entity table is not unique on this entity number as it has another internal key. ie it contains duplicate msg_entity_no

The problem I am experiencing is that when multiple messages are produced , multiple instances of the MDB query's for existence on the entity table at the same time.
At that time it does not exist for either instance and the process then inserts for both messages. As opposed to one insert for the non-existent entity 
and then updating the record for subsequent messages.

I want to get away from using the annotation @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "1") and deploying to the deploy-hasingleton folder which only allows one instance of the MDB as this is not scalable.

Comment: Are you running in a cluster environment ?

Comment: How are your primary keys defined?

Comment: We are in a clustered environment. The table has a primary key with another internal entity number.

Comment: @Patrick can you limit the MDBs to only one instance in the cluster ? I.e Only have the one mdb instance on one jboss instance ?

Comment: @KennethClark We managed to achieve that with the maxSession annotation and the deploy-hasingleton folder however if that instance goes down messages will no longer be consumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition you are receiving is due to either `DUPLICATE` or `SAME DATA` contained with in messages which are placed in the queue within quick succession. There are a couple of solutions for this.

1) DEQUEUE On one JBOSS instance with only one mdb. This means you will have ONE MDB running on one JBOSS SERVER in the cluster, messages will be essentially processed in sequence.

2) Create a locking mechanism whereby you create a table write the message contents to that table with a PRIMARY KEY and the message contents. You then filter out or create an ordering of data to be processed based on the contents. This will slowdown execution time but you will have better auditing for your data. You will in essence have two `ASYNC` process jobs. One to populate you data from the `QUEUE` and another to PROCESS the data. You could do this one minute later.

3) Some QUEUE Implementations such as ORACLE AQ have a `dequeue condition` which can be set Messages in the queue are evaluated against the condition, and messages that satisfy the given condition are returned.  TIBCO have strategies for Locking which protect the thread of execution when multiple threads in an agent.

References 
   http://tech.chococloud.com/archives/2152

Not understanding the business process, I would suggest you try prevent the "DUPLICATE" messages from the source.

Comment: thanks ... option 2 sounds viable for my purposes. And you are correct about the source being polluted, will attempt to address it there first.